# How to clear cells in range that are of currency format without looping

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure this is a question for here, so shoot me if it's not!

I have a spreadsheet that contains data of both number and currency format. I am to delete the values in the cells that are of currency format **only**.

I can do this with a simple `For Each` loop, however, due to the size of the spreadsheet this is not efficient.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ClearCurrency()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set myRange = Selection

    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00" Then
            cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I have read up on [VarTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) and [.NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) but am unable to piece together a more efficient solution.

I know I cannot store the information to an array to loop through, so is there a faster way?

Comment: SearchFormat and ReplaceFormat might do this? Nice question =)

Comment: Don't forget to set `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` before the loop (and back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` after the loop) so that you're not recalculating the entire workbook once for every cell!

Comment: If there were more conditionals than the currency type. You could insert the sheet inside an array and then loop through it using `VarType(arr(i, j))` if the result is 6, means it's currency type. You could use it along another conditionals and that'd be the most efficient way. If the only criteria is currency type as has been already said, replaceformat is the way.

Comment: What about Range.SpecialCells? https://www.stl-training.co.uk/b/specialcells-in-vba/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proposed in comments, you could use `SearchFormat` and `ReplaceFormat` to do this, something like the following:

```
Sub ClearCurrency()

If Not TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .FindFormat.Clear
    If .DecimalSeparator = "." Then .FindFormat.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    If .DecimalSeparator = "," Then .FindFormat.NumberFormat = "\$#,##0.00"
End With

Selection.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

---

***Noteworthy***

Whilst working on non en_US local settings and making use of custom numberformat `"$#,##0.00"` you may encounter an `Error 1004` warning. The format is not recognized and will error out. To prevent this you can either; make use of `NumberFormatLocal`:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormatLocal = "$#.##0,00"
```

Notice the difference in both decimal comma and grouping character. A second option would be to escape the sequence with a backslash that indicates that the following character should be used literally as is:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "\$#,##0.00"
```

Now the decimal point and grouping character can stay in place. Therefore we need a check to test the local settings, which can be done with `Application.DecimalSeparator`, as proposed in the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
Set myRange = Selection

Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
myRange.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False
```